# How do I get all drive-locations of a file in Google Drive with Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I want to list all locations in Google Drive of a specific file. I can't find any information about it in the Driveapp reference.

I have a file that is in multiple locations: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lZ91BVZKslqtzbdm0QsREmT_O7ikbc_Y

How can I get these location using Google Script.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Found what I was looking for. Will post is below as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my own question. The code below will get all locations of a file:

```
function listFileLocations() {

var file = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxxx");
var fileParents = file.getParents();

while (fileParents.hasNext()) 
   {
   var folder = fileParents.next();
   Logger.log(folder.getId());
   } 
}
```